# How to deal with correlated variables

Tags: mixed-model, correlation, linear-model, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I would like to know how to deal with correlated variables, with this kind of correlation matrix:

[image]

Is there a way to combine the correlated variables such as all the AV.. variables or FF.. variables?

How can I deal with that kind of correlation matrix, knowing that I want to reduce the number of variables to apply a mixed effect model on the data?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of techniques for automatic variable selection and dimension reduction. One of the best known is Principal Component (PC) Analysis. Whether this makes sense here depends on the meaning of your variables and what the aim of analysis is. It implicitly summarises variables that are strongly correlated, however every variable will contribute (more or less) to every PC, and this may not allow the kind of interpretation of your results that you have in mind (if this refers to the individual variables).

There is much work on automatic variable selection that uses the response, but this is problematic in the sense that technically it will affect the distributions of estimators in the final model and therefore invalidates standard assumptions. (I'm not saying it should never be done though.)

In any case, my first approach would be to think about the meaning of variables, and whether they can be summarised by a lower number of scores that are meaningful and good to interpret.

Another question is whether FF and AV are deterministic functions of the other FF and AV variables (such as sums or means), in which case the summary variables don't add information, may lead to trouble fitting the model (in case of collinearity), and should be discarded, as long as all the other variables are in the model.

An alternative approach is to define another score that summarises all the information in the FF variables in a meaningful manner, and to use that score instead all the individual variables, same for AV. This needs to take their meaning into account; however in principle you could also run a PC Analysis on the FF (AV) variables only and take the first resulting PC as a summary. This also allows you to quantify the percentage of variation in the respective group of variables explained by the PC.

Comment: I agree with this, but where in the question does automatic variable selection come in? Did I miss something?

Comment: @PeterFlom I just mentioned it because some people would want to do that in this situation (as they may want to make statements about the individual contributions of the individual variables).

Answer (score 4):

Two common methods are [factor analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/factor-analysis/info) and [principal component analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/pca/info). (My links go to the tag wikis; you can also scan the questions with each tag). Both of these have been discussed here many times and have lots of details, but, briefly, factor analysis attempts to find latent variables in a large set of variables. A latent factor is a variable that cannot be directly measured.

PCA is a pure dimensionality reduction method. It attempts to find linear combinations of variables that capture as much of the variance in the original variables as possible.

From your question, it seems to me that FA may be more suitable, as you seem to have some idea of latent variables connected to the prefixes of the variables.

There is also partial least squares, which is often more useful when your goal is regression. But you say will have a mixed model. I googled PLS for mixed models and it appears that there aren't well-established methods for this.